# Do I need to specify parameter in Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Changing a local variable.</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var add = (function () { /* do I need to put x in this statement? 
                         like "var add = (function(x) { " */
                  var counter = 0;
                  return function (x) {return counter+=x}
        })()

        add(10);
        add(15);
        alert(typeof(add));
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(20);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that in the example above, add is assigned to the return value of a self invoking function.

The self-invoking function only runs once. It sets the counter to zero (0), and returns a function expression.

My question is why the function isn't defined like:

```
var add = (function(x) {
....
}()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not passing in any arguments:

```
//              Receive the arguments...
//                  v
var add = (function(x) {
....
}()
//^
//That you pass in here.
```

This self invoking function returns another function. It's that function (the returned function), which accepts the parameter `x`.

Comment: your explanation is so great, nice and easy to understand!

Answer (score 2):

Consider anonymous functions like a function that makes a function (in this case). So, do you need to know `x` to make a function that uses a parameter `x`? Basically, no because you only need to know it when that function which you create inside the anonymous function is actually invoked.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to create a self-executing anonymous function that returns a definition of a function which is set to "add". A better (and less confusing) way would be to define the function as so:

```
var add = function(x) {
    //Do things
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent: the code in the question uses 'counter' as accumulator variable, and it is in a closure, so no one except the function add can access to it. In your code you'd have to declare a global variable which could be modified by any other piece of code.